# How do I solve this error with Silenium Web Driver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(updatedCarLinks[0]) #This has a list of links that I need to look but will but this in a for loop later
time.sleep(2)

h1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//h1')
print(h1)
```

I keep getting the following error screen. I have been looking at it on other posts and can't seem to figure out why this error is happening.
`selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: target frame detached` <--- Error

Answer (score 0):

Is the selenium crome driver compatible with you chrome version? Check the versions match or is supported by the driver.

More information on what exact versions are used would be helpful

Comment: The chrome driver is compatible. I checked that already and it matches my version of chrome.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).